# MS CRM (4.0): Reports - Filtering Imported Reports

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm

I have created a complex report in Microsoft Business Intelligence. 
The report has its own (fairly complex) WHERE clause. Is it possible for the user to set the CreatedOn date as part of the criteria?

**UPDATE**

I was looking at this again. On a basic report (one table) if i import the report over one created with the report wizard, this give you the filter options and works.

On the more complex report that uses the union statement to pull data out of two tables the filter options are available however they have no effect, this is after removing the where clause.

**END UPDATE**

Thanks
Luke

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question. Have you looked in the Report Writers Guide? Article "Using Filters in a Report" seems to be the right starting point. Search the SDK for CRM_FilterText. I'm guessing you'll have to parse this string for the values you want to add to your where clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been doing some research into this topic, and it appears that if you alias the fields and prefix them with CRMAF_ this allows you to add filtering. I'm going to look at this over the next few days and see how it works. However it has been noted that several people have been unable to get this to work correctly.

Please note you need to prefix both the table and fields.

You then can set the filter.

Comment: Yea, let us know how it goes.  Luckily I haven't had to write many reports for SSRS/CRM yet, but this type of thing will probably be common for any serious report.

Comment: Just noticed I never got back to anyone. This works really well.